# How to create a method that takes a generic class as a parameter

Tags: c#

I've been searching S.O and elsewhere for an answer to this question, and I can't find one that is helping me understand my problem.  I'm new to C#, so that might be part of the issue.

I'm trying to get a handle on how to pass a class (or a copy of one) as a parameter to a method.  However, I want this method to accept any class I pass it, not a specific one.

So for instance:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name{ get;set; }
}

class Bob : Person
{
    public Bob(){ Name = "Bob"; }
}

class Fred : Person
{
    public Fred(){ Name = "Fred"; }
}

Fred aFred = new Fred();
Bob aBob = new Bob();

// below is where I need the help, I don't know the syntax for what I'm trying to do.
SayName(aBob,aFred);

static public void SayName(person1,person2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(person1.Name + ", " +person2.Name) // I'd like this to output "Bob, Fred"
}
```

Okay, I know that above syntax isn't correct insofar as passing those classes as parameters or in accepting them as arguments for the method, but I'm hoping that you can see what I'm trying to do.  I'd like to be able to pass any class deriving from Person to the SayName method, and have it output whatever its name happens to be.

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Seems like you have a misunderstanding of OOP. your classes `Bob` and `Fred` should not be classes unless they define a different **behavior** than their base class `Person`. They should only be instances of `Person`, with their respective `Name` property. That's what Properties are for, to have instances of the class carrying different data.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification.  Now, by "behavior" do you mean that it would have new methods associated with it?  What would be the correct way to declare an instance of a class if I was only going to change properties?

Comment: Yes, by "behavior" I mean different methods and additional code. If you need an instance of person with a specific name just do `var bob = new Person { Name = "Bob" };`

Comment: Thanks HighCore, it is appreciated.  I'm all of two days into C# so I'm hitting some simple stumbling blocks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just pass them as `Person`:

```
static public void SayName(Person person1, Person person2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(person1.Name + ", " +person2.Name) // I'd like this to output "Bob, Fred"
}
```

Comment: So simple!  Thanks for the quick response, that was exactly what I was looking for.  Hopefully that helps some of my fellow c# noobs.

Answer (score 0):

Type is not declared as parameters in SayName, seems to be a misunderstanding in understanding how to pass parameters. Use Person type for both parameters say person1 and person 2 the code will run

```
public static void SayName(Person person1, Person person2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(person1.Name + ", " +person2.Name)
}
```